# Extract VSCode SCSS for another Electron based project

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to build a new GUI from scratch but using VSCode styles?

I need:

- main GUI
- left buttons
- left folder
- editor area (monaco with multiple tabs)
- footer

Comment: What does it refers to `VSCode styles`?

Comment: I need all VSCOde internal SCSS with an example of GUI built on it without any JS